# update from schema A to schema B on different instance only if values are different

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have schema A on host A with employee names etc. i have schema B on host B with travels cost by employee. the ID_EMPLOYEE key is the same on both schema.
schema A is update with new names (for anonymized process). I need to update names fields on schema B from new names on schema A.
Note that when adding new names (new employee) the application add it on both schemma A and B but only schema A is anonymized.

Don't know how to do that with so less SQL skills

Comment: . . Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Is there another key to join on? If a.ID_EMPLOYEE changes but a.EmployeeName stays the same and is unique, then just write an update statement on b to update b.ID_EMPLOYEE. Something like

```
UPDATE b
SET b.ID_EMPLOYEE = a.ID_EMPLOYEE
FROM b
JOIN a
ON b.EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName
```

Edit: that is MS SQL syntax. Here's an oracle friendly version

```
UPDATE b
SET b.ID_EMPLOYEE = (SELECT a.ID_EMPLOYEE
                 FROM a
                 WHERE b.EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.ID_EMPLOYEE
                 FROM a
                 WHERE b.EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName);
```

If there's no other unique field to match on in b and the old a.ID_EMPLOYEE is not maintained anywhere after the update occurs, then you have to have a "middle-man" table that stores the old a.ID_EMPLOYEE and b.ID_EMPLOYEE. If you have that table (let's call it c), then it's just a two step process to update c, then update b.

Comment: Oracle does not support the update join syntax. Use `MERGE` instead.

Comment: Oh jeez, I get a downvote for semantics.. You can use an update, you just need to nest the join - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php see "Example - Using EXISTS Clause" - I've edited my response to include.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in fact, all id_employee in schema b, i have to update employee_name if is not the same as schema A employee_name for the same id_employee